# Truncated DNS PTR query response in Netty 4.1.13.Final

Tags: pointers, dns, netty, truncated

I'm using Netty to do forward and reverse lookups and it's working well. One thing I've run into though when doing a PTR lookup of an hp.com IP address (15.73.104.147) is that a large result set is truncated.

When using dig -x 15.73.104.147, I can get a result but I noticed that it too has a truncated response and so successfully switches to TCP mode - 
    ;; Truncated, retrying in TCP mode.

If there any way of doing something similar with Netty given that the DnsNameResolverBuilder needs a DatagramChannel instance?

thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

Netty itself not support DNS over TCP atm. What you could try is increase the datagram packet size that is expected via `DnsResolverBuilder. maxPayloadSize(....)`.

https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/resolver-dns/src/main/java/io/netty/resolver/dns/DnsNameResolverBuilder.java#L249

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Norman. In this case it's not helping and so for now it may not be an issue but I may need to revisit it later on.